# Replacing `chardev` by `mmap`

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, mmap, chardev

I am looking for a way to synchronize a kernel driver and some user-land code (without any copy_to_user or polling on a mmap)

**More explanation**:

My user side code read some data in a shared mmap, but it needs to know when the data are ready from the driver
I already try to use signals to schedule everything but performances are even lower than using a regular char device (with a copy_to user)

(Working on a 4.1.15 kernel)

Any idea ?

[EDIT] I trying to do it with msync now

Comment: Does the driver not face the other side of the issue -- knowing when it can safely modify the contents of the mapped memory?  How does it address that, and why does that not yield a solution for the userland side as well?

Comment: The mmap is a circular buffer where the driver writes data and keeps track of the write_offset.
Named semaphore would have been perfect here, but there is no implementation on the kernel side.